# dbf slow connection over network

Tags: vb.net, performance, connection, oledb, dbf

I'm working on a visual studio 2012 project which using vb.net.

In the project, the program need to link back (using oledb) to an old school .DBF database. 
During development stage, which the db allocated in localhost, everything work fine.

Now, when implementing the program, which the database is sit in a server the connection become horribly slow.

All the clients who using the program facing the same problem when opening the program or retrieve data from the database.

Example,

Opening an Employee List Table, around 20 records with 2 columns.

Local : took around 1 second to load.

Over Network : took more than 5 minutes to load.

Anyone here facing the same problem before and any solution that may overcome this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps Your Slow Network Connection Or Firewall And Antivirus causing the problem .

Comment: I think the network/firewall/antivirus is not causing the issues. I have another application which written in FoxPro Language did not encounter the issues but my Visual Studio project is encountering slow performance issues. I tried to retrieve one records from my DBF file, which should took less than a second in Local, but when over network, it took more than 30 seconds to retrieve the one row data, in 1 table.

Answer (score -1):

I've been working on a similar application recently and I found that hosting DBF files from anything other than a windows server 2003 server showed similar SLOW results as to what you are describing... Something about how that server version serves files(I think it's related to opportunistic locking somehow) allows the client machines to receive the DBF data at a rate closer to what you were seeing at the development stage.

Overall I think doing anything other than allowing an DBF files for import to another type of database type (ie SQL ).. is a waste of time nowadays... DBF files are terrible and as you are learning don't serve well anymore anyway. Go XML or SQL or both! :)